# Scala Try, Else, Except block

Tags: scala, error-handling, try-catch

I have code like this:

```
val extractInfo: (Array[Byte] => String) = (fp: Array[Byte]) => {

  val parser:Parser = new AutoDetectParser()
  val handler:BodyContentHandler = new BodyContentHandler(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
  val config:TesseractOCRConfig  = new TesseractOCRConfig()
  val pdfConfig:PDFParserConfig = new PDFParserConfig()

  val inputstream:InputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fp)

  val metadata:Metadata = new  Metadata()
  val parseContext:ParseContext = new ParseContext()
  parseContext.set(classOf[TesseractOCRConfig], config)
  parseContext.set(classOf[PDFParserConfig], pdfConfig)
  parseContext.set(classOf[Parser], parser)
  parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, parseContext)

  handler.toString
}
```

A function literal that parses text from PDFs using Apache Tika.

What I want, though, is a Try block in here that runs on parser.parse and returns an empty string if it cannot execute.  I am not sure how to construct this sort of logic in Scala.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/Try.html).

```
val extractInfo: (Array[Byte] => String) = (fp: Array[Byte]) => Try {
  val parser:Parser = new AutoDetectParser()
  ...
  handler.toString
} getOrElse("")
```

What this does is catch any error in the body and recover from this error by returning the empty string.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Note, this scala.util.Try class differs from the (lowercase) scala try/catch/finally keyword syntax. It took me a while to notice the upper case "T", so maybe this will help someone else. (Also, the link above is broken so I referenced it's permanent import location).

Answer (score 2):

You can just write

```
try {
  val parser:Parser = new AutoDetectParser()
  val handler:BodyContentHandler = new BodyContentHandler(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
  val config:TesseractOCRConfig  = new TesseractOCRConfig()
  val pdfConfig:PDFParserConfig = new PDFParserConfig()

  val inputstream:InputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fp)

  val metadata:Metadata = new  Metadata()
  val parseContext:ParseContext = new ParseContext()
  parseContext.set(classOf[TesseractOCRConfig], config)
  parseContext.set(classOf[PDFParserConfig], pdfConfig)
  parseContext.set(classOf[Parser], parser)
  parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, parseContext)

  handler.toString
} catch {
  case e: Exception => ""
}
```

because `try` is an expression in Scala, just like `if` or `match`. However, if you intend to use `""` as a sentinel value (that is, check later whether an error happened by checking if the result is empty), don't; use `Option[String]` or `Try[String]` as the return type instead.